# Trying to add menu option using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

Trying to add menu option but my code crash. tried multiple ways to add but not sure how to do that. any hint will helpful.!!!

I tried many ways posted on google also tried to write some code but somewhere it's fail to bind Menu and Tkinter

Any references will appreciate.

Comment: There is no menu in your code?

Comment: I tried to writing code but it keep crashing. Not sure where I need to write.

Comment: I'm new to programming and I'm confused now where to add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `tk.Menu` and add commands using `menu.add_command`. [Read here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm) for more information about tkinter menus and how to do things like adding submenus. For your code, you can add a menu like this:

```
...
tk.Tk.__init__(self)
#self._GUID()
self.x = self.y = 0
self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
self.menu.add_command(label = "Menu command name", command = self.doSomething)
self.config(menu = self.menu)
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=512, cursor="cross")
...
```